# TypeORM + TypeError: Cannot set property EntityManager of #<Object> which has only a getter

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I have a Nest application which is not starting due to the following exception. I am not sure what is the cause of the problem.

I created [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/saulotoledo/typeorm-jest-issues) to replicate the issue. The running instructions are detailed in the README.

The error:

```sh
TypeError: Cannot set property EntityManager of #<Object> which has only a getter
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/saulo/NodeProjects/typeorm-jest-issues/node_modules/typeorm/index.js:120:23)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1147:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1167:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:996:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1036:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/saulo/NodeProjects/typeorm-jest-issues/node_modules/@nestjs/typeorm/dist/common/typeorm.utils.js:5:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1147:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1167:10)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with the tslib dependency. You can find more info here:

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/6054

But a temporary solution to start your project is to add tslint@1.11.2 as a dependency (`yarn add tslib@1.11.2`) and to add this to your package.json

```
 "resolutions": {
   "tslib": "1.11.2" 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That solved my issue. I editted your answer and added `yarn add tslib@1.11.2` to it.

Comment: Try to change import
`
import * as typeorm from 'typeorm/globals';
`