# TypeError: Cannot set property EntityManager of #<Object> which has only a getter

Tags: typeorm

I'm pretty new to using Typeorm, when i try to set up a connection I get the error:

```
export {EntityManager} from "./entity-manager/EntityManager";
        ^
TypeError: Cannot set property EntityManager of #<Object> which has only a getter
```

version of typeorm =>  "typeorm": "0.2.21",

I tried to downgrade typeorm to 0.2.0, but then I get a problem with my postgres version.
Did anybody else had the same issue?

Comment: I have the same issue from yesterday. But it was working with no issues... this happens just when I run "npm install --no-shrinkwrap --production".

Comment: Check this: [Entity manager Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61778771/typeorm-typeerror-cannot-set-property-entitymanager-of-object-which-has-on)

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with `tslib` 1.12 that is used by `typeorm`. It is suggested to downgrade it for now.

Related question: [Can't init TypeORM project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61779561/cant-init-typeorm-project)

Comment: so when I do downgrade, I get a different error:

error: error: column cnst.consrc does not exist

using tyorm@0.2.0 and postgres 11.7

Comment: actually, it does work with the work around in the post above, THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I resolved the issue compiling  the app using npm  install  --production  taking off --no-shrinkwrap

Just copying package.json  and package-lock.json.

I am using the latest typeorm  available.